# PSAT/MATLAB GUI error Reference to non-existent field

Tags: matlab, user-interface, export, matlab-figure

I am trying to use PSAT 2.1.11 with Matlab R2015b, when i export figures I got the following error:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'axesplot'.

Error in fm_plot (line 484)
  axs_pos = get(Hdl.axesplot,'Position');
 
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback''
```

The problem is on the file fm_plot.m which is attached here [fm_plot](https://pastebin.com/ZKaBuCxX)
I have tried reinstalling PSAT and Matlab, but the error persists. I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you,

I want to export figures as ''.fig'' from the PSAT GUI but i got this error

Comment: That looks like a bug. Did you contact the author? There’s not much of an answer anyone here can give you.

Comment: Yes, but no response

Comment: So what do you expect from this community? What is your question? Are you hoping someone will fix the code for you?

Comment: Yes, I would like someone who has encountered the same problem when exporting figures from PSAT GUI to assist me, hopefully.